# Intermittently Calling [NSUserDefaults synchronize] Returns Success but isn't shown during ObjectForKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsuserdefaults

I have 2 applications sharing data via the NSUserDefaults, initWithSuite ID. Using iOS Dev Center.

One in 2 attempts the following code block apparently fails to write my dictionary object to the shared UserDefault area, I use the BOOL response from Synchronise to check the success. eg, (4 NSData objects, one, or more, or all of the items might fail to write to storage).

I use [[NSUUID uuid] UUIDString] as a key **[EDIT: Been told in comments that this changes value?, Tried a Static String same result, 25% fail rate]**

Any help will be greatly received.

**Writer - Application 1**

```
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]
                          initWithSuiteName:FRGFileShareID];

NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

[myDefaults setObject:**customObjectDict** forKey:uuid];

BOOL successSave = [myDefaults synchronize];
if (!successSave) {
     DLog(@"Failed To Save To Defaults");
}
```

**Reader - Application 2**

```
NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:FRGFileShareID];

if ([myDefaults objectForKey:uuid]) {
    [mediaArray addObject:[myDefaults objectForKey:uuid]];
    [myDefaults removeObjectForKey:uuid];
}
```

If i log out [[myDefaults dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] im lucky if any of my keys are there.

Again with this working 75% of the time, im not sure whats causing the intermittency but its killing the usability of my feature.

Comment: [NSUUID UUID] will create a new unique identifier every time you call it. Have you set up App Groups in the plist?

Comment: @MattRees Thanks for the response, i think i understand why people have been asking about it. That UUID generation is inside a for loop, as is the setObject. Think the issue must be around saving files as NSData to a plist. Going to switch the implementation to using FileManager i.e. containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier.....

Answer (score 0):

You have not pass the value to NSUserDefault, change the code like this,

```
[myDefaults setObject:uuid forKey:"myDict Object"];
[myDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: The uuid is just the key, the object im passing through is just a dictionary, doesnt matter what it is, Im reading the same UUID key to output from user defaults. Im setting my object and calling synch. 75% of the time it works, 100% it returns success.

Comment: @Woodmister1 why do u make the key a uuid, what if it changes

Comment: Once you have generated a UUID as a string im saving it, so it shouldnt mutate while in storage. And for 3/4 of the time this process works fine. Ill edit my question to remove the placeholder string of "myDict Object", seems to be causing confusion.

Comment: @Woodmister1: I have just checked what you try to do. I have found that the UUID value changes all the time, I put the NSLog once I set the UUID value and then check it before retrieving it. And when UUID values are same it goes inside the if condition. You can also put NSLog and check the values of UUID.